# Reduce doesn't work with user defined function with /;

Tags: functions

I want to use Reduce to my own function, but it generates the error message: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce. Here is a simplified example.

```
test[x_] := x^2 - 3 /; 0<x<10;
test[x_] := -1 /; 10<x

Reduce[test[x]<1, 0<x<5]
```

I think `/;` makes the problem. However, how can I define the domain of my own function without using `/;`?

Comment: `Piecewise` lets you define such functions. Also it probably should be `Reduce[test[x] && 0<x<5, x]`.

Comment: @Natas gave the answer, I just wanted to add that `/;` is a programming construct. It is not meant to represent mathematical ideas. It is meant to implement algorithms.

Comment: I think I remember people saying that `Boole` had been incorporated into many functions in Mathematica. `test[x_]:=((x^2-3)*Boole[0<x<10])+(-1*Boole[10<x]);
Reduce[test[x]<1&&0<x<5,x]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize insightful comments, `Piecewise` is the appropriate construct to express the mathematical idea of a piecewise function, [as Natas suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225052/reduce-doesnt-work-with-user-defined-function-with#comment572884_225052). [`Condition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) (i.e. `/;`) is a *programming* construct. As [Szabolcs mentioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225052/reduce-doesnt-work-with-user-defined-function-with#comment572886_225052), "it is not meant to represent mathematical ideas; it is meant to implement algorithms". In the following, note also the corrected syntax for [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html).

```
Clear[test]
test[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2 - 3, 0 < x < 10}, {-1, x > 10}}]
Reduce[test[x] < 1 && 0 < x < 5, x]

(* Out: 0 < x < 2 *)
```

As an alternative approach, [Bill proposed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225052/reduce-doesnt-work-with-user-defined-function-with#comment572889_225052) using [`Boole`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html):

```
Clear[test]
test[x_] := ((x^2 - 3)*Boole[0 < x < 10]) + (-1*Boole[10 < x]); 
Reduce[test[x] < 1 && 0 < x < 5, x]

(* Out: 0 < x < 2 *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Piecewise works very well. However, when I try to compare with the other user-defined function, it takes forever.... For example, Reduce[{test[x]>test2[x],0<x<2}] never returns the output... If I take the expressions out from the user-defined functions, then it works well. For example, Reduce[{x^2 - 3 > x + 2, 0<x<2}] works well. How can I make user-defined functions practically callable inside of Reduce?

Comment: What are the definitions of `test` and `test2`? Does it make a difference if you add the variable to be solved for explicitly, as we have been suggesting? `Reduce[{test[x] > test2[x], 0 < x < 2}, x]`