# Can I confine the codomain when drawing plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to confine the codomain of my plot. For example, I want to draw y=f(x) only when 3x<y<7x+3. If not, want to draw y=0.

Is it possible in Mathematica plot?

Comment: Just as suggested in your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/225052/1871), use `Piecewise`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use Piecewise in this case? In my previous question, I confined the domain, not codomain.

Comment: do you have an example of f(x)?

Comment: Just confine the codomain as you confined the domain.

Comment: It's a bit complex, but let me give a simplified example. y = (1/2) * (2H-2L+2*sqrt(H(H-L)(1-a))). And want to draw a graph only when y1< y <y2 (y1 and y2 are function of H, L, and a).

Comment: So you have 3 independent variable `H`, `L`, and `a`? What do you want? A `DensityPlot3D`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_?NumericQ] := x + x^2; (*made one up, since none was given *)
g[x_?NumericQ] := Piecewise[{{f[x], 3 x < f[x] < 7 x + 3}, {0, True}}];
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is `f[x]`

```
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It works very well even for the very complex multi-variate functions. Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, what ?NumericQ stands for?

Comment: @Chris it is to insure these functions are called only for numerical input, by the Plot command that is. Since these only make sense with `x` is numerical, due to the comparison being made.

Comment: One can also use `ConditionalExpression[f[x], 3 x < f[x] < 7 x + 3]` to avoid the extension by zero that one gets with `Piecewise`.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you so much!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Great point! You read my mind. Thanks!

Comment: +1; however, the `NumericQ` is not necessary here since both `f` and `g` can evaluate symbolically. `NumericQ` is normally used when the function uses a numeric technique (e.g., `NSolve`, `FindRoot`, `NDSolve`) which would fail when the argument is nonnumeric.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Can I combine multiple ConditionalExpressions into one function? For example, can I define the function as f[x] if 3x<f[x]<7x+3 and g[x] if 0<g[x]<3x using ConditionalExpressions?

Comment: @Chris Actually I discovered just yesterday that if you put `Undefined` as the default in `Piecewise`, it is automatically converted to a `ConditionalExpression` + `Piecewise` expression.  So something like `Piecewise[{{f1, cond1}, {f2, cond2},...}, Undefined]`.

Answer (score 1):

`PlotRange -> {{<domain>}, {<codomain>}}` is the way to set the codomain in its normal meaning.

But the OP has in mind restricting the region that is plotted, and that task can be handled with `RegionFunction`.

```
Plot[10 (x - 10) Sin[x], {x, -2, 80},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 3 x < y < 7 x + 3]]
```

[image]